# Why there is no response using git protocol to clone project?

Tags: git

I try to clone a `Linux` branch from `git://git.kernel.org` to local machine:

```
# git clone git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/acme/linux -b perf/core
Cloning into 'linux'...
```

But there is no response. Use the `tcpdump` and `Wireshark` to check the captured packets:
[image]
We can see the `TCP` connection was established. But after client sent request using `git smart protocol`, there was no any response.

Could anyone give some clues?

Update:
(1) According to @MariaInesParnisari suggestion, using `--verbose` flag, but it doesn't show more information:

```
# git clone git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/acme/linux -b perf/core --verbose
Cloning into 'linux'...
Looking up git.kernel.org ... done.
Connecting to git.kernel.org (port 9418) ... 147.75.110.187 done.
```

(2) Change to `https` protocol, it worked:

```
# git clone https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/acme/linux -b perf/core --verbose
Cloning into 'linux'...
POST git-upload-pack (gzip 25015 to 12570 bytes)
remote: Counting objects: 5287534, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (807310/807310), done.
```

Comment: Try adding the `--verbose` flag and post the output

Comment: @MariaInesParnisari Updated, thanks!

Comment: Could this perhaps be a company firewall preventing the connection? (I see that you get a syn ack back from git.kernel.org. My net-sec knowledge is a bit rusty but I think FWs sometimes sends this in place of the host, deliberately trying to cause a timeout, which prevents the client from overloading the FW.)

Comment: @visibleman you mean the company firewall sends a faked `SYN ACK` to the git client, so my `SYN` request is not sent to real `kernel.org`. Is my understanding right? Thx!

Comment: @NanXiao, Yes I think that is certainly a possibility that the company  firewall sends a "spoofed" SYN ACK in order to protect itself (Typically seen on the inbound connections, but in some cases also on outbound connections). I also don't know if there might be special concerns  regarding this in your country.

Answer (score 1):

I never managed to clone from work using the git protocol: it uses the special port 9418, which is always blocked.

Only https is working/allowed, git and ssh are usually blocked (for outbound connections, since ssh is allowed for servers within the intranet)

Comment: How to explain the `ACK` from `147.75.110.187`? Do you think it is a faked one? Thanks!

Comment: @NanXiao I think this is part of the "Connecting to git.kernel.org" part. But once it actually tries to communicate through that port, it should be blocked.